# Why is PFC done 'equipment-side'?

Tags: power-factor-correction

I have only a basic understanding of power factor correction, but I am curious why it is necessary for manufacturer's and their customers to be concerned with ensuring a high power factor, other than to avoid larger bills* from the electricity supplier.

Why does the supplier not - that is why *can* they not, I assume - perform this correction with some large capacitance on their end?

*To clarify, I mean manufacturers of large equipment, and their *industrial* customers buying that equipment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the two scenarios: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7q81i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the top scenario a reactive load is power factor corrected back at the source of power and the current flowing down the wires (dotted box) will be, for UK AC and a 0.1 henry load this: -

Current = \$\dfrac{230V}{2\pi\cdot 50Hz\cdot 0.1H}\$ = 7.32 amps

In the lower scenario the power factor correction is done right up at the load and, because the capacitor and inductor are pure components (and perfectly in antiphase) the current flowing down the wires is ZERO.

This means cable power dissipation is zero in scenario 2.

Comment: Ah, I see! Seems like a really stupid question now. Basically, if you correct at the source, then the reason you were correcting to begin with isn't solved, since current flows too far before the correction?

Comment: Correct and power is wasted in the cable.

Comment: Additional reason : PFC at the equipment side is part of the installation and belongs to the equipment : it should be disconnected when you disconnect the equipment, and shipped to a new site when the equipment is shipped...

Answer (score 3):

The problem with non-power factor corrected loads is that they present an impedance other than purely resistive to the power line, with the reactive part of the impedance storing charge from the source during one part of the AC cycle and returning it during another.

This charge isn't used to do work in the load but - since it moves back and forth through the resistance of the mains wiring -  is converted to heat (as an I²R loss) and is wasted.

Large energy-consuming customers are charged for reactive power by the energy supplier and, as a consequence, tune their loads to be resistive and thereby save that expense if it's substantial.

Small commercial and residential customers don't ordinarily pay for the reactive power they waste, so the concern isn't about larger bills; rather it's about the waste affecting the utilities' capacities and its cost to the environment.

The problem with trying to correct power factor at the source is that even if all of the loads' reactances could, somehow, be  summed and presented to the source as a single impedance,  compensating for that lumped reactive part of the impedance at that point would lead to wild variations and fluctuations of voltage at the various load sites.

Compensating at each of the load sites, however, would render all the loads resistive, with the effect that as they were connected and disconnected from the mains, in parallel, all that would happen is that the source would see only a changing resistance and would supply the current required to satisfy the changing demand.

Comment: My reference to larger bills was meant in regards to industrial customers who, like you point out, do pay for VARs. So in a hypothetical (and of course totally fictional) network where the load is constant at every customer, for all time, you could correct at the source?

Comment: No, you can't correct at the source, because that would miss the whole point of having the current and voltage be in-phase *throughout the distribution network*, which is where the reactive power turns into real loss.

Answer (score 1):

Power factor correction goes well beyond just making the voltage and current in phase.

The use of switching devices has increased the harmonics and distortion on the power grid. Most electric utilities in U.S. now have maximum amounts of harmonic distortion permitted. So, it is not just a matter of paying for the extra usage of imaginary power.

Electrical power service can and will be denied to large industrial users who exceed the maximums permitted for harmonic distortion.  Europe (EU) has general required standards for power factor correction (including harmonics) for all mains connected devices.